# For Google Maps Is there a code for Oceans just like countries in ISO 3166-2?

Tags: google-maps

For Google Maps Is there a code for Oceans just like countries in ISO 3166-2?

I need to be able to highlight industry standard ocean areas (North Atlantic, etc) in google maps to show where fish are being harvested around the world.  Are there any pre-defined codes supported by google maps / google earth for bodies of water?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**No.** ISO 3166 is for political boundaries only. The closest thing it has to codes for oceans is the common convention in the user-assignment "X" range to use "XZ" for International Waters. If anybody does use ISO-style codes for the oceans, it is by their own invention.

For example, the CIA World Factbook, which uses the alpha-2 codes for the URL of each country, places the pages for the oceans into user-assignment "X" or otherwise unassigned codes: the Atlantic Ocean is [ZH](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/zh.html), the Pacific Ocean is [ZN](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/zn.html), the Indian Ocean is [XO](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/xo.html), the Arctic Ocean is [XQ](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/xq.html), and the Southern Ocean is [OO](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/oo.html).

According to [Google's GeoMap API documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geomap.html), you should be able to just use "Atlantic Ocean". Is that not working?